# Get button value in ejs when onClick

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Let's say I have these buttons in my ejs file

**file.ejs**

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<listBrand.length; i++) { %>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" value="<%= listBrand[i]%>" id="brandName" onclick="multiple(this.value);">
         <%= listBrand[i]%>
        </button>
        <br/>
 <% };%>
 <script>
      function showList(id) {
          var list = document.getElementById(id);
          list.style.display = (list.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
      }// a div id = "id" is hidden on this page, clicking will make it becomes visible.

      function multiple(value) {
           showList("listGallery");
           console.log(value);
      }
 </script>
```

The page will render 5 buttons with the following values: `LEXUS`, `TOYOTA`, `FERRARI`, `MAYBACK`, `AUDI`. I want to declare a variable in ejs that is equal to the value of a button when it is pressed. (For example, if I click the button `LEXUS`, then `<% var b = 'LEXUS'%>` is run.)

I have searched for the keywords "Pass value from javascript to EJS", but it's only declare javascript by EJS only.

And I think it's pretty hard, especially the button has `onClick`.

All I need is to get each button value when clicking on each of them and pass it to an ejs variable. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EJS is server side, onClick/JS button handling is client side. You can't set a value in EJS based on user input without making a round trip to the server. You could set a GET/POST parameter when the user clicks and then hit the same route again with the new parameter and set the variable based on that parameter. My guess is that there is a better way to accomplish your goals than that, but I don't know what your actual end goal for this form is.

Comment: Actually I have a list of cars stored in mongoDB. I want when user click on a button with the car brand, it will shows a list of cars based on that brand, for example, LEXUS will show all cars with brand LEXUS, and so on.  I don't want to make the page reload when clicking a button so I load all list, and find base on that list, no need to go back to load.

Comment: If you are already loading all of the lists in the initial template render, just use Javascript (native/JQuery/whatever) to dynamically hide the lists based on the button click in the client. EJS is for serverside rendering only, for anything else use standard client side JS DOM manipulation.